# Is it possible to define a norm ||•|| on R^2 such that (1,0),(0,1) have norm 1 and ||(1,1)||<1?

Tags: normed-spaces

Is it possible to define a norm ||•|| on R^2 such that (1,0),(0,1) have norm 1 and ||(1,1)||<1?
 I don’t come up with any idea.
I don’t know this assertion is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\|(x,y)\|=\frac 3 4 |x-y|+\frac  1 4 |x+y|$.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand.

Answer (score 0):

$\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2-(7/4)xy+y^2}$ should do.